# android play games services "your application is incorrectly configured" just when I publish it

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I've been working on an android game that uses Google play services and it was working great on Eclipse ADT, correctly configured and all, but when I published it, I got the message "the application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID... ". But it worked on Eclipse, so what am I doing wrong? I really don't know how to explain any more than this, but can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

found how to solve it: used the debug.keystore located in my .android folder when I was exporting my APK

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours of researching, i found the solution to fix this error successfully:

When developing, make sure you sign the **SHA1** with you **debug.keystore** NOT release keystore.

 Good luck!